# Client caching overrides custom Last-Modified when rendering a View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, http-headers

I recently started working on a MVC.NET project and soon noticed there was no caching of the front-page. Setting `[OutputCache(Duration = 60), Location = Client]` on the Index() method added the right `Expires` headings, but since `Last-Modified` was set to the time the page was created the caching would never kick in.

As an experiment, I then manually tried setting the `Last-Modified` header to some time in the past, to see how that worked, but it seems as if is being overwritten somewhere! I added this code to the end of my Index() action:

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2015-12-01");
    var timeString = dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("R");

    var v =  View("Index", homeViewModel);
    Response.AddHeader("Last-Modified", timeString);

    return v;
```

Even though I could debug and inspect the headers in the Response and see the header being added, the returned page in the browser still had `Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Mar 2016 15:34:12 GMT` (the current time). My manually set header was thus overwritten by some other code after the action returned.

What is causing this behaviour, and how can I manually set the last-modified timestamp to enable caching?

---

**Addendum**

using `Location = ServerAndClient` will make client caching work again, which beats me as somewhat odd ... If, so what use is the `Client` option? How can it ever work?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Location=client means only the web browser (or some other client) is having any caching done. Not on the server. Is that your intention?

Comment: Another possible location is proxy servers. So, you actually get to pick and choose where you'd like your cached content to reside.

Comment: You are probably on to something ... I thought setting Client would just set the required headers, which then would make the browser pass the corresponding headers to the server, which would then only send new responses if there was a never result on the server. Meaning the server never cached anything, it generated a new response and checked if there were any modifications. If the content was changed, it would send the content with a new Last-Modified and HTTP 200, and if not, HTTP 304.

Comment: @SRQCoder Can you name a scenario where setting Location=Client would actually make the browser _not_ call the server on a refresh? Because currently, I am refreshing the browser to see if it will use a cached version or do a server call, and it calls the server every time (along with a Cache-Control: max-age=0).

Comment: Exactly. And something else to point out is OutputCache happens at the controller level. So, if you have code in your View (like show this stuff only if IsAuthenticated) it very well may not execute at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `OutputCache` attribute that is overwriting the relevant headers I pass along. Removing that will make it possible to set whatever headers I like.

---

And to answer the second question of when the Client option makes sense, be aware that you will never see any effect when refreshing the browser window. It is only when you click links that the browser will decide if it should reuse the cached version.